# Creating a Core Data Inverse Relationship

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to write my first Cocoa app, and Core Data is making it difficult to model my data objects. I have two entities that I want to manipulate: `Account` and `Transaction`. `Account` has a human-readable name and that's about it. `Transaction` stores a monetary value, and references to two accounts called `debitAccount` and `creditAccount` (I'm working on a double-book accounting app).

I want to be able to find all the `Transactions` for a given `Account`, whether they use `debitAccount` or `creditAccount`. How can I do this? Is there a way to do it that will work easily with Cocoa UI binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked best (and made the most sense) to me was to create a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to use as my `Account` entity:

```
@interface Account : NSManagedObject {

}
-(NSArray*)getTransactions;
@end
```

I have the actual lookup logic inside `-getTransactions`, which wasn't too hard to do by hand. This is working out well so far, especially because the method name conforms to KVO.

To make Core Data return `Account`s instead of `NSManagedObject`s, I had to change the entity's "Class" property in Xcode's data modeling tool.

Comment: Be careful. The reason for inverse relationships is that they help to ensure the model's consistency. If you delete an object that's the target of a relationship and it has no inverse, you have to make sure to remove it from that relationship, or else you'll end up with invalid references.

Comment: That method shouldn't be named "-getTransactions" because it doesn't return a collection of transactions by reference.  Use "-allTransactions" or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want Transaction to be related to Account via two relationships: `debitAccount` and `creditAccount`, yes? And you're wondering about creating inverse relationships.

In short, a relationship can only be the inverse of one other relationship. So you won't be able to create a relationship called, say, `transactions` that is the inverse of both `debitAccount` and `creditAccount`. Instead, you'll have to create two relationships, like `debitTransactions` and `creditTransactions` (I'm sure you'll think of more appropriate names for these...)

Now, since relationships are modeled as sets (specifically, `NSSet`s), you can union the `creditTransactions` and `debitTransactions` relationships for a particular Account to get all transactions that account is involved with.

A (possibly better) alternative would be to introduce an intermediate entity, with a name like `TransactionAccount` that has a to-one relationship to both `Account` and `Transaction` as well as an attribute, like `accountRole` that identifies the account as being the debit or credit account relative to that particular transaction. You'd create inverse to-many relationships on both `Transaction` and `Account` with a name like `transactionAccounts`. That way, you could write something like this:

```
[account valueForKeyPath:@"transactionAccounts.transaction"]
```

to get all the transactions for a particular account. You could use an `NSPredicate` to filter the set to only transactions where the account was the debit/credit account.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I found a way that worked for me, but your input helped.